# How to pass a bitfield and a bit inside it to a function

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

With microcontrollers you usually have a register and its bitfield version that enables you to get access to each pin individually

Suppose i have two objects from two bitfield

```
struct {
        unsigned a_A:1;
        unsigned b_A:1;
        unsigned c_A:1;
        unsigned d_A:1;
        unsigned e_A:1;
        unsigned f_A:1;
        unsigned g_A:1;
        unsigned h_A:1;
        }A;
struct {
        unsigned a_B:1;
        unsigned b_B:1;
        unsigned c_B:1;
        unsigned d_B:1;
        unsigned e_B:1;
        unsigned f_B:1;
        unsigned g_B:1;
        unsigned h_B:1;
        }B;
```

how to build a function that accepts a bitfield and one of its bits as parameters
Just like

```
void my_func(bitfield,bit_name)
```

bit_name should varies for each type of the bitfields

Comment: Use a macro instead of a function?

Comment: What is my_func going to do with the bit name?  Normally, register bits are defined like this: `#define REGB_BITNAME 0x40`.  That way, your register can just be defined as an integer and you can use bit functions to set, test, and clear each bit in the register.

Comment: The various occurencies of `bitfiled` should read `bitfield` or `bitfilled` perhaps?

Comment: the structs should be re-written to contain a union, where one union segment is named (say) bits and contains the bit definitions, usually as the actual names of the bits.  where one union segment is named (say) byte and is defined as a char.  It also helps if an image of the register is kept in ram, then for writes, update the image, then write the whole image to the register,  for reads, read the register into the image, then pick bits from the image.  This avoids the problem of certain registers being modified by the read/modify/write cycle

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
void my_func(unsigned a_B);
...
void my_func(unsigned h_B);
```

and calling it:

```
my_func(B.a_B);
...
my_func(B.h_B);
```